# volumetric density from linear densities in the three directions x,y,z

Tags: geometry, density

I have a cube and I know the linear density of particles along each axis (I mean- the number of particles per unit length along each axis). How can I get the volumetric density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates just take a volume element as dV = dx*dy*dz.  The volumetric density is determined by multiplying the linear densities by each other. This gives you the volumetric density as # of particles/m^3

Comment: Even if $\rho_x=\rho_x(x)$ and so on?